# Two variable function continuity

Tags: calculus

$$f(x,y)=
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x^2y \over x^3+y & \mbox{if } x^3+y \neq 0 \\ 
0 & \mbox{if } x^3+y = 0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

So how do I find out whether this function is continuous? My problem was using the condition, because it isn't continuity at a point.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fix $y=1$, what happens when $x\to-1$?

Comment: $f(x,y)$ approaches infinity? But how do you write it down formally?

Comment: You just need to show that $f(x,y)$ is not continuous at the point $(-1,1)$, which you can do from the definition of continuity.

Comment: As Tim suggested, you need 1 counterexample, i.e. 1 "good path", to prove that your function is not continuous at the points on the locus $x^3+y=0$. Approaching the point $(-1,1)$ on $x^3+y=0$ along any convenient path does the job.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, all that is needed is a single counter-example.  A convenient point for the counter example is $(-1, 1)$.

Comment: Typo. (1,-1) or (-1,1).  At (1,1)  function is continuous.

Comment: @LawrenceMano fixed the typo, thanks